# Adding fields to a Data Access Class in Acumatica

Tags: c#, acumatica

Very new to Acumatica and any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

I've added a new field via the DAC on the Projects screen. After the project is created,  the field is populated with a custom project id which is an integer.

Here is the code:

```
namespace PX.Objects.PM
{
  public class ProjectEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ProjectEntry>
  {
    #region Event Handlers
    protected void PMProject_RowInserted(PXCache cache, PXRowInsertedEventArgs e)
    { 
      var row = (PMProject)e.Row;
      row.UsrProjectID = 90000; //Custom Field with value
    }
    #endregion
  }
}
```

But when validating the project it returns the error:

> \APP_CODE\Caches\ProjectEntry.cs does not contain a definition for 'UsrProjectID' and no extension
> method 'UsrProjectID' accepting a first argument of type
> 'PX.Objects.PM.PMProject' could be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?)

After checking the DAC, I found that the new fields were added to the DAC **ContractExt.usrProjectID**, how can I add it the PXProject DAC or call the field from the code event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following line in order to access the DAC extension

`ContractExt myext = PXCache<Contract>.GetExtension<ContractExt>(row);`

`myext.UsrProjectID =...`

Comment: Thanks. This did allow me to get access to the field, how can I store that value? I've tried it through the RowUpdating Event, but no luck.

Comment: cache.SetValue<ContractExt.UsrProjectID>(row,9000);